# Where is my connectionstring stored in a class library?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, connection-string, class-library

I've just generated some EF models from my EDMX designer in a *class library*. I chose to create a new connection string because the one that I defined in my `app.config` wasn't picked up. So Visual Studio (i guess) created a new connection string for me called: `pc-name.db-name.dbo` (see screenshot).

**However I can't seem to find where this connectionstring is stored, it sure isn't in my app.config.. But where is it?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

[image]